# Counting Principles

Tags: probability, self-study

Please help with the concepts being questioned here:

In how many ways can all the letters of the word TRIANGLE be arranged if:

i) The letter A is placed before the letter N and the letter G can only be placed after the letter N?

ii) The vowels should not be placed next to each other?

iii) Exactly two vowels are to be placed next to each other?

Thanks

Comment: Please can you show us your workings so far ? This is not a free homework-answering service, but if you can tell us where you are confused, or show your workings so far, many people will be happy to help.

Comment: I am unsure as to where to start. My workings wouldn't direct the solution any further; it would merely create a mess that would upset all the people willing to give me answers. I know that this service is not a homework-answering service. I'm trying to learn. I need direction. If I can't be provided with that here, then I guess I misunderstood the functionality of Stack Exchange. I don't need to be reminded what this site does. Why do I need to make questions personal in order for them to warrant a solution?

Comment: I didn't say you need to make anything personal. Many people here are teachers or lecturers. Your workings are absolutely relevant, and if your workiings are faulty then there is a good chance you will receive some useful guidance.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.